# error message only if $user not equal

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following code which correctly assigns sessions if both arguments re true (ie. username and password match database record).  If the username and password don't match the database I want to echo out a message to the user.  However, the message only echo's out if the username doesn't match.  If the password doesn't match but the username does, no error message but also no session?

Here is the php code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title ID="current">Home</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        include("NavAndHeader.php");
        include("db_conn.php");
        session_start();

        if(isset($_POST['signIn'])){
            $user=$_POST['userName'];
            $password=MD5($_POST['password']);

            $query = "SELECT *
                FROM users
                WHERE username='$user'";

            $result = $connection->query($query);
            $count = $result->num_rows;

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if ($row['Password'] == $password && $row['Username'] == $user){
                    $_SESSION['status'] = $row['Access'];
                    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['Name'];
                    header('Location: ./Home.php');
                }
                else{
                    echo "<p id='logInError'>Those details are incorrect</p>" ;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
        <div id="logIn">
            <table>
                <form method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Username:</p></td>
                        <td><input name="userName" type="text" id="userName" size="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="20"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="signIn" value="Submit">
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="./SignUp.php">Sign Up</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>    
        </div>
```

Comment: Username this should be username

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont have to check the `username` as you are fetching according to the `username`.

```
WHERE username='$user'"
```

I think this would be enough and make the error more specific. -

```
       if ($count > 0) {
            if ($row['Password'] == $password){
                $_SESSION['status'] = $row['Access'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['Name'];
                header('Location: ./Home.php');
            }
            else{
                echo "<p id='logInError'>Password incorrect</p>" ;
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p id='logInError'>Username incorrect</p>" ;
        }
```

Comment: this is not correct . it states that if any one of them is right then the whole art is true that means either username or password or password any one of them is right and other is wrong then still it comes as true.

Comment: why he cannot go with both. let me know?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh when fetching with username (`WHERE username='$user'"`) only the records having the username will be fetched as AFAIK. Then why do you need to check the both in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for the answers.  I did not have any luck using either directly however the sgt BOSE solution was close.  I just made sure the if($count > 0) was before the while loop and it worked perfectly.  I have attached the relevant section from my new code.

```
if($count > 0){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if ($row['Password'] == $password){
                        $_SESSION['status'] = $row['Access'];
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['Name'];
                        header('Location: ./ass2Home.php');
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<p id='logInError'>Those details are incorrrect</p>" ;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "<p id='logInError'>Those details are incorrrect</p>";
            }
```